# C# - How to control chrome browser

Tags: c#, google-chrome, webbrowser-control

I wanted to make an application wherein you specify the name of the websites, your username and password and that application automatically logs in to all your accounts in the specified websites. I have done this using windows form application, using a web browser. But i wanted my application to open all these websites in chrome and log it in there. Plz Help

Comment: Chrome has a fairly extensive extension API which would probably allow you to do this - why are you writing it as a C# application?

Answer (score 3):

I'd check out the chrome API failing that
Look into getting a handle to the window through window API calls

But why not just a chrome extension?!? Miles simpler

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: You should elaborate as to why this is a good option, instead of just posting a link.

Comment: ..and why would he want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick Google search for "chrome C# api" turned up a number of results I think you may find relevant.

I thought the following were particularly promising, if you're willing to accept a few concessions:

- [Automating Chrome Browser from C#](https://markcz.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/automating-chrome-browser-from-csharp/)
- [ChromeDevTools](https://github.com/MasterDevs/ChromeDevTools); a C# Library to interact with Chrome's Developer Tools
- [Chrome Debugging API](http://blog.masterdevs.com/chrome-debugging-api/)