# how to get time of the browser tab when it gets closed using C#? In other words is there any query to get start time and end time of a tab on browser?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, service

how to get time of the browser tab when it gets closed using C#? In other words is there any query to get start time and end time of a tab on a browser?

Comment: could you use signalR for that...since its a connected web process?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at one of the following:

- Windows API, specifically [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx), and the chrome window hierarchy (eg tab windows will be nested inside the main chrome window)
- [chrome.windows api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows)

Once you've decided on one of the above, you will need to poll the chrome browser every second to decide if tabs have been opened/closed.

Comment: can you tell how to connect this  chrome window API with my  c# application

Comment: Take a look at the following answer. If you want more help, post the code you've tried and state the problems you are experiencing! ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120468/control-chrome-programmatically