# Reading the request and response data from network tab of chrome using C# process

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, redirectstandardoutput

In my C# application I am starting a chrome process with specific URL using System.Diagnostics.Process. So, the chrome window is opened and series of URL's are triggered in chrome. I want to find if there is a way to read all of these requests and response data from network tab of chrome inspect window.

Comment: You can not access properties of tabs in chrome process. You have to do it from chrome API. look at these links: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/resources/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120468/control-chrome-programmatically/42120612

Comment: You might be interested in a [command line switch to tell Chrome to log to a file](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging). Your program could just read from the file.